# Pass variable to another PHP file and execute it

Tags: php, mysql

I want to send a variable that I receive in a PHP file that is sent from an Android APP relative to a mysqli query and execute the second PHP file based on the variables received. For example:

In 'file1.php' I receive two variables sent from the Android APP:

```
$month= $_REQUEST['month'];
$year= $_REQUEST['year'];
```

Then, I want to send these two variables to 'file2.php' and execute the query on it.
I don't need to receive any information from 'file2.php' just execute the query in it, which records some data to a Mysql database.

I used an include command in file1.php like

```
include 'file2.php';
```

which works well but I have to hardcode the variable in 'file2.php', like

```
$month= '5';
$year = '2019';
```

What I want is to send the variable I receive in file1.php

```
$month= $_REQUEST['month'];
$year= $_REQUEST['year'];
```

and resend it to file2.php

Comment: I suggest that you use `$_GET` instead. these variables will exist in your url and can be accessed everywhere.

Comment: did you include file2.php before or after saving the requests to the variables?

Comment: Remove the hard-coded variables, set them - *then* include `file2.php`.

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou after I receive (requests) the variables.

Comment: @RonaldHaan I don't have any proble in receive  the variables in file1.php, I just don't know how to resend them to file2.php

Comment: As long as your variables are set before you include `file2.php` they WILL be available in `file2.php`.

Comment: @Qirel the hard-coded variables I used is just to test if file2.php was working correctly. The hard-coded variables is in file2.php just because I don't how to receive them from file1.php

Comment: @JoseBorges As I said, *remove* that definition in `file 2.php`. Then define your variables in `file1.php`, and after that include the file `file2.php`.

Comment: @Dave thank you, it worked, did not know was that simple

Answer (score 0):

SESSIONS is another option here, Session variables can be used to access those variables across the pages.

```
<?php
    // file1.php
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    $month= $_REQUEST['month'];  // check for sql injections and XSS
    $year= $_REQUEST['year'];  // check for sql injections and XSS

    $_SESSION['month'] = $month;
    $_SESSION['year'] = $year;

?>
```

Remove hardcoded values and replace with sessions,

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    //file2.php
    /*
        remove hardcoded values and replace with 
        $month= '5';
        $year = '2019';
    */

    $month= $_SESSION['month'];
    $year = $_SESSION['year'];

    /*
    your logic goes blow
    */

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$value="this value";

include 'file2.php'; 
include 'file1.php';
```

The `$value` will be visible to both of the classes.

so just use the variables in `file2.php` both would already be visible to `file2.php`